# Why is ioctl call not passed to sys_ioctl?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel, ioctl

I have kernel module (4.4.32 kernel) which implements ioctl call by assigning it's ioctl handler to `struct file_operations`'s `unlocked_ioctl` pointer. All works fine, but I was given program (binary only), compiled for 2.6 or maybe 2.4 kernel which doesn't make kernel registering a call to ioctl for my module if I start this program on my 4.4.32.
Because this program was compiled on older kernel it uses older ioctl interface, i.e. `ioctl` pointer in `file_operations` structure, not `unlocked_ioctl`.

The older program creates a console for visual interaction with user and must be run as root from root console.

I did strace on that program and checked that the program receives `ENOTTY` for 2nd ioctl, so I have written test program which makes same ioctl calls to the kernel module that fault program does.

I have verified that trace recorded by strace is the same for both programs for these ioctl, i.e. thay are called with same arguments, in same sequence.

The relevant part of my test program is:

```
/*--------------------------- ((( STEP 1 ))) ---------------------------*/
hsdfd1 = open(PCIHSD0, O_RDWR);
if (hsdfd1 < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error on OPEN, can't open [%s] [%s]", PCIHSD0, strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
}

/*--------------------------- ((( STEP 2 ))) ---------------------------*/
uint8_t xsts;
err = ioctl(hsdfd1, HSDGETXSTS, &xsts);
if (err < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error HSDGETXSTS [%s]", strerror(errno));
    close(hsdfd1);
    exit(2);
}

/*--------------------------- ((( STEP 3 ))) ---------------------------*/
hsdfd2 = open(PCIHSD0c, O_NDELAY, O_RDONLY);
if (hsdfd2 < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error on OPEN, can't open [%s] [%s]", PCIHSD0c, strerror(errno));
    close(hsdfd1);
    exit(3);
}

/*--------------------------- ((( STEP 4 ))) ---------------------------*/
err = ioctl(hsdfd2, PCIHSD_DIAG_SETALLOWDC, 0x1);
if (err < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error PCIHSD_DIAG_SETALLOWDC [%s]", strerror(errno));
    err = 4;
    goto exit;
}
```

The straces:

My test program:

```
execve("./hsddebug", ["./hsddebug"], [/* 23 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0xb89000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f9231c6b000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=105359, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 105359, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f9231c51000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0P\34\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1738176, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3844640, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f92316a2000
mprotect(0x7f9231843000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f9231a43000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1a1000) = 0x7f9231a43000
mmap(0x7f9231a49000, 14880, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f9231a49000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f9231c50000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f9231c4f000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f9231c4e000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f9231c4f700) = 0
mprotect(0x7f9231a43000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f9231c6d000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f9231c51000, 105359)          = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x400826, [INT], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f92316d70e0}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
open("/dev/pcihsd0", O_RDWR)            = 3
ioctl(3, PHN_GETREG or RTC_PIE_ON, 0x7ffec60e3643) = 0
open("/dev/pcihsd0c", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK) = 4
ioctl(4, 0x70c0, 0x1)                   = 0
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 1), ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f9231c6a000
write(1, "\n", 1)                       = 1
write(1, "OK\n", 3)                     = 3
close(3)                                = 0
close(4)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Fault program:

```
execve("./pcihsd", ["./pcihsd"], [/* 18 vars */]) = 0
uname({sys="Linux", node="debian", ...}) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x83bb000
brk(0x83dc000)                          = 0x83dc000
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x804848f, [INT], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x806ab28}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {0x804842b, [QUIT], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x806ab28}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
open("PCIHSD.hlp", O_RDONLY)            = 3
old_mmap(NULL, 266240, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfffffffff76d7000
ioctl(1, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_NEXT_DEVICE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
access("/root/.terminfo/l/linux-fk", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/usr/share/terminfo/l/linux-fk", R_OK) = 0
open("/usr/share/terminfo/l/linux-fk", O_RDONLY) = 4
read(4, "\32\1/\0\35\0\20\0}\1a\3", 12) = 12
read(4, "linux-fk|linux console with sF9 "..., 47) = 47
read(4, "\0\1\0\0\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\1\1", 29) = 29
read(4, "\377\377\10\0\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\10\0@\0\22\0", 32) = 32
read(4, "\377\377\0\0\2\0\4\0\25\0\32\0!\0%\0)\0\377\3774\0E\0G\0K\0W\0\377\377"..., 762) = 762
read(4, "\7\0\r\0\33[%i%p1%d;%p2%dr\0\33[3g\0\33[H\33[J"..., 865) = 865
read(4, "", 1)                          = 0
read(4, "", 10)                         = 0
close(4)                                = 0
ioctl(1, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_NEXT_DEVICE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(1, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_NEXT_DEVICE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(1, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_NEXT_DEVICE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(1, TIOCGWINSZ, {ws_row=64, ws_col=160, ws_xpixel=0, ws_ypixel=0}) = 0
ioctl(1, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_NEXT_DEVICE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(1, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_NEXT_DEVICE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
brk(0x83fd000)                          = 0x83fd000
ioctl(1, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_NEXT_DEVICE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(1, SNDCTL_TMR_STOP or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_GINFO or TCSETSW, {B38400 opost isig -icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(1, SNDCTL_TMR_STOP or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_GINFO or TCSETSW, {B38400 opost isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTSTP, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTSTP, {0x805d130, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x806ab28}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, NULL, {0x804848f, [INT], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x806ab28}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {0x805d310, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x806ab28}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGWINCH, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGWINCH, {0x805d410, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x806ab28}, NULL, 8) = 0
ioctl(1, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_NEXT_DEVICE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(1, SNDCTL_TMR_STOP or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_GINFO or TCSETSW, {B38400 opost isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
write(1, "\33[1;64r\33[0;10m\33[4l\33[?7h\33[?25h\33[?"..., 34) = 34
rt_sigaction(SIGTSTP, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x806ab28}, {0x805d130, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x806ab28}, 8) = 0
write(1, "\33[H\33[J\33[24d", 11)       = 11
rt_sigaction(SIGTSTP, {0x805d130, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x806ab28}, NULL, 8) = 0
write(1, "\33[?25l\33[?1c", 11)         = 11
open("PCIHSD.dft", O_RDONLY)            = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/dev/pcihsd0", O_RDWR)            = 4
ioctl(4, PHN_GETREG or RTC_PIE_ON, 0x80cd480) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, {0x804950f, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_INTERRUPT|SA_NODEFER|SA_RESETHAND, 0x806ab28}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
open("/dev/pcihsd0c", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK) = 5
ioctl(5, 0x70c0, 0x1)                   = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
close(4)                                = 0
close(5)                                = 0
```

As you can see, in both cases the relevant ioctl calls are same, i.e:

```
open("/dev/pcihsd0", O_RDWR)            = descriptor1
ioctl(descriptor1, PHN_GETREG or RTC_PIE_ON, 0x7ffec60e3643) = 0
open("/dev/pcihsd0c", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK) = descriptor2
ioctl(descriptor2, 0x70c0, 0x1)                   = 0/ENOTTY ???
```

Question1:

What can be the reason that the second call to ioctl (that with cmd 0x70c0) doesn't get the kernel's sys_ioctl/vfs_ioctl functions called when it is executed by (old) fault program (I have a breakpoint set on running kernel - the call is not recorded by the kernel, even though the call to first ioctl is properly recorded and the breakpoint is hit for both programs)?

Question 2:

Where to insert the breakpoint to debug this? Why I do not see `sys_ioctl` being called at all in the fault program case?

---

EDIT:

Thanks to Wumpus Q. Wumbley for the answer to Question1.

Answer to Question 2 is:

When `compat_ioctl` is implemented by the driver, then the `compat_SyS_ioctl` is called and not `compat_ioctl`. It is called from `do_syscall32_irqs_on`/`do_syscall_32_irqs_off`, which are called from `entry_INT80_compat`.
Also `sys32_pread`/`SyS_pread64` is called from `entry_INT80_compat` for `struct file_operation`'s `read` handler.

Comment: `unlocked_ioctl` was created for kernel driver compatibility, I.e. to avoid breaking divers that didn't support a re-entrant ioctl.  I don't believe userspace need know which is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the different pointer values in the `strace` results I can see that the one that works is a 64-bit program and the one that gives `ENOTTY` is a 32-bit program.

You need to define a `compat_ioctl` to make your driver support 32-bit programs.

Comment: But how to exaplain the same values of arguments to ioctl? As we can see the correct values have  been passed do what actually fails here?

Comment: If it helps, you can imagine that `ioctl` is really 2 different syscalls. When a 32-bit process calls `ioctl` on a 64-bit kernel, it's really calling `compat_ioctl`. It must be separately implemented in each driver because of the generic nature of the `void *` argument. The kernel can't translate the value from 32-bit userspace format to an appropriate 64-bit format for the driver, because it doesn't know whether it's a pointer to `int`, `short`, `char[]`... Only the driver knows. Other syscalls don't have this problem (e.g. `read` uses a `void *` but it always points to an opaque byte array).

Comment: compat_ioctl is called from sys_ioctl isn't it? The problem is there is no call to sys_ioctl visible in the kernel if compat_ioctl is not enabled (I have a breakpoint on sys_ioctl set). So what is called in that case?

Comment: I don't know the details, and I have failed to find any documentation aimed at driver authors explaining how `compat_ioctl` is supposed to be implemented. Maybe if you post a new question with a title like `How do I add a compat_ioctl to a driver?` you can get someone better qualified to answer

Comment: I do not have problems with addding compat_ioctl functionality to this driver. I have added that and it works now. I do not understand why I haven't seen a call to sys_ioctl been made when comapat_ioctl was not used. Let me look into this again and maybe I will find the answer.

Comment: I have just found the answer. compat_SyS_ioctl is called and not compat_ioctl. It is called from do_syscall32_irqs_on/off, from entry_INT80_compat.